# How to order french or german words in aggregation correctly (special chars)?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have follwing problem when i try to order e.g. in german the terms:

- Frankreich
- Ägypten
- Zypern
- Algerien

i always get the **wrong** order:

- Algerien
- Frankreich
- Zypern
- **Ägypten**

but i want to get the "Ägypten" after "Algerien":

- Algerien
- **Ägypten**
- Frankreich
- Zypern

I have the same behaviour for french (e.g Égypte) and polish (e.g. Łotwa) too.

My aggregation query part:

```
'aggs' => 
array (
  'lawInternational' => 
  array (
    'terms' => 
    array (
      'field' => 'lawInternational.singleWords',
      'size' => 10000,
      'shard_size' => 10020,
      'order' => 
      array (
        '_term' => 'asc',
      )
    )
  )
```

Will be happay about any idea.

**Addition**

I use the following definition of the "lawInternational.raw" field:

```
            'lawInternational' => ['type' => 'string',
                'analyzer' => 'text_analyzer',
                'fields' => [
                    'singleWords' => ['type' => 'string',
                         'analyzer' => 'comma_analyzer'],
                    'raw' => ['type' => 'string',
                        'index' => 'not_analyzed'],
                    'autoSuggest' => ['type' => 'string',
                        'analyzer' => 'suggest_analyzer']]],
```

The "comma_analyzer" is defined as:

```
            'comma_analyzer' => ['type' => 'custom',
                                 'tokenizer' => 'comma_tokenizer']],
             'tokenizer' => ['comma_tokenizer' => ['type' => 'pattern',
                                                   'pattern' => ',']],
```

Comment: Are you performing any analysis on the `_term` field? If so, that may be affecting how terms are sorted.

Comment: I hope this addtionla information helps you. What do you mean by "_term"-field is this a special internal field like '_id'? If yes, i do not do any stuff on this field.